# WSO2 API Manager(wso2am-4.0.0) - Callback URL Not Getting Recognized

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using wso2am-4.0.0 and I created an application to enable code grant type. However, even after entering the callback url, it doesn't get recognized in the devportal.

[image: Call back URL can not be empty when Implicit or Authorization Code grants are selected.]

Comment: Are you using the GA release of APIM 4.0.0?

Comment: I downloaded the release from Github.

Comment: This might be a bug in the GA release. If you don't have a WSO2 subscription, you can try with the GA release of APIM 4.1.0 or try with the 4.0.0 service pack available in the website (https://wso2.com/api-management/previous-releases/). Otherwise, you can update the 4.0.0 to latest update level and try.

Answer (score 1):

In the APIM 4.0.0 vanilla pack, I was able to successfully add the callback URL with the same set of grant types as yours. Please check if there are any spaces in front of the entered URL.
[image]

If that isn't the case, then can you try restarting the server or downloading the APIM 4.0.0 vanilla pack again from the [WSO2 official site](https://wso2.com/api-management/previous-releases/)?